# Android Intent to Amazon application

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

Has anyone worked with Intents to launch Amazon application with a query string?
Looking for the answer I came across the Amazon official API guide and they give this uri:

```
amzn://apps/android?s=
```

That's the website I found it on: https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/sample-code/deeplink.html

So I have tried it like that:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("amzn://apps/android?s=ps4")));
```

The code doesn't throw exception but my app stops working. Has anybody got any idea about it?

Comment: Your code works fine on my Nexus 7 and Kindle Fire HD 7". Which device are you testing with? Can you provide the output from logcat?

Comment: it doesnt throw any exception but it crashes the app. What does it show when you run the code?

Comment: [Here is a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/SYpTSX3.png).
logcat should show the error...Can you double check it is showing all messages (no filter)? Also which device are you using?

Comment: OK its working now. I didnt have the Amazon Appstore app installed before. BUt what i really meant to do was to launch and search the Amazon Mobile shopping application instead of appstore. Any idea how I would do that? And I dnt want to launch a website, I need actual mobile app ...

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the Amazon Appstore installed.  It's not in the Google Play Store, you have to get it here: http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/get/android

As long as you are doing a check to make sure it's on an Amazon device, you should be fine!  Otherwise, you are better off using the Amazon HTML link (http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME).  Either way, this is how I do it.

```
if (android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("Amazon"))
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("amzn://apps/android?p=YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `Intent.ACTION_MAIN` ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN

Comment: I have tried that and it still crashes the app. Maybe the URI :amzn://apps/android?s= works only for US version of the app. (maybe that's the case)

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas